# taking derivative of a polynomial (void version)

Tags: java, linked-list

I need to write a method which takes derivative by modifying the current polynomial. I could write one that works with a return type. Here's the code:

```
public PolynomialSortedList differentiate() {

    PolynomialSortedList res = new PolynomialSortedList();

       for(PolyNode tmp = poly; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next)
        {
           if(tmp.exp != 0)
              res.addTerm(tmp.coef * tmp.exp, tmp.exp - 1 );

        }
       return res;
}
```

How can i turn it into void using this upper part of the code:

```
public class PolynomialSortedList implements Polynomial {
    private PolyNode poly;
    private double TOLERANCE = 0.00000001;

    public PolynomialSortedList() { 
        poly = null;
     }

    private static class PolyNode {
        int coef;
        int exp;
        PolyNode next;

        PolyNode(int coef, int exp,PolyNode next) {
            this.coef = coef;
            this.exp  = exp;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you call differentiate by saying `myPolyList.differentiate();`, then you might try swapping `return res;` with `this.poly = res.poly;`. The only catch is that right now, that wouldn't quite work since `poly` is `private` and you have no way to get the first poly from a polyList.

EDIT: A little more information about how your program is set up would help me give a more specific answer.